# How do you end a pipe with an assignment operator?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I want to end a pipe with an assignment operator in R.

my goal (in pseudo R):

```
data %>% analysis functions %>% analyzedData
```

where data and analyzedData are both a data.frame.

I've tried a few variants of this, each giving a unique error message. 
some iterations I've tried:

```
data %>% analysis functions %>% -> analyzedData
data %>% analysis functions %>% .-> analyzedData
data %>% analysis functions %>% <-. analyzedData
data %>% analysis functions %>% <- analyzedData
```

Error messages:

```
Error in function_list[[k]](value) : 
  could not find function "analyzedData"
Error: object 'analyzedData' not found
Error: unexpected assignment in: ..
```

Update:
the way I figured out to do this is:

```
data %>% do analysis %>% {.} -> analyzedData
```

This way, to troubleshoot / debug a long pipe, you can drop these two line into your pipe to minimize code rerun and to isolate the problem.

```
data %>% pipeline functions %>% 
   {.}-> tempWayPoint
   tmpWayPoint %>% 
more pipeline functions %>% {.} -> endPipe
```

Comment: `analyzedData <- data %>% analysis functions`

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading; what you _really_ want to do is interleave an assignment into a pipeline, not end it.

Comment: @Hong-Ooi I arrived here because my question was the one in the title, and indeed, that turned out not to be the question. But for others like me wanting the answer to that question, the answer is the infix function `[<- ()`. (I can't get the backticks right; `[<-` is in backticks). The first argument is the object to subset and then assign (so that gets piped in), the next arguments are the subsets of the dimensions of that object (one for each), and the last is the object to assign to that subset, or overwrite it with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's probably easiest to do the assignment as the first thing (like scoa mentions) but if you really want to put it at the end you could use `assign`

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(m = mean(hp)) %>% 
  assign("bar", .)
```

which will store the output into "bar"

Alternatively you could just use the `->` operator. You mention it in your question but it looks like you use something like

```
mtcars %>% -> yourvariable
```

instead of

```
mtcars -> yourvariable
```

You don't want to have `%>%` in front of the `->`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do the trick. Do you know the relative merits of using '{.} -> endPipe' vs 'assign("endPipe", .)' ? I see that assign allows you to specify the environment as an argument. Other than that, is one better than the other if we're only interested in assignment to the current environment? Is it just stylistic differences?

Comment: I've tried this, but the assign doesn't work. The code evaluates, but I don't get a new object called "bar".

Comment: @ccoffman You should get a new object called 'bar'.  It would evaluate in the current environment so if you're doing that inside of a function and then looking for "bar" after the function exits then yeah 'bar' won't exist anymore.  That's more an issue of scoping though.

Comment: I had the same problem as coffman. The code was not running in a function, as @Dason suggested. Changing the assign statement to assign("bar", .,envir = .GlobalEnv) did solve the problem though. I am using R version 3.4.1.

Comment: Using assign() in this way with pipes does not work in R 3.5.2 with marittr 1.5. Use the pos= argument to explicitly set the environment to assign the variable into (pos=1 for instance). Alternatively, follow @Wilbert and use the envir= argument.

Comment: @t.kalinowski and for posterity: one reason for using assign() instead of `->` is that you can construct the variable name using something like paste(). Check out the example in ?assign() for a toy use case!

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're trying to decorate the `%>%` pipeline operator with the side-effect of creating a new object. One would assume that you could use the assignment operator `->` for this, but it won't work in a pipeline. This is because `->` has lower precedence than user-defined operators like `%>%`, which messes up the parsing: your pipeline will be parsed as `(initial_stages) -> (final_stages)` which is nonsensical.

A solution is to replace `->` with a user-defined version. While we're at it, we might as well use the `lazyeval` package, to ensure it will create the object where it's supposed to go:

```
`%->%` <- function(value, x)
{
    x <- lazyeval::lazy(x)
    assign(deparse(x$expr), value, x$env)
    value
}
```

An example of this in use:

```
smry <- mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %->%   # ->, not >
    tmp %>%
    summarise(m=mean(mpg))

tmp
#Source: local data frame [32 x 11]
#Groups: cyl
#
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#..  ... ...   ... ...  ...   ...   ... .. ..  ...  ...

smry
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#  cyl        m
#1   4 26.66364
#2   6 19.74286
#3   8 15.10000
```

Answer (score 5):

You can think of a pipe chain as a multiline function, that works as every other multiline function. The usual way to save the output is to assign it on the first line :

```
analyzedData <- data %>% analysis functions
```

Like you would do :

```
plot <- ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=x)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: The OP wasn't asking "how do I do an assignment?".  OP was asking "If I prefer to have my assignment at the end of the pipe, how do I go about it?".    As such, your answer may be seen as condescending.

Answer (score 4):

Update: the way I figured out to do this is: `data %>% do analysis %>% {.} -> analyzedData`

This way, to troubleshoot / debug a long pipe, you can drop these two line into your pipe to minimize code rerun and to isolate the problem.

```
data %>% pipeline functions %>% 
   {.}-> tempWayPoint
   tmpWayPoint %>% 
more pipeline functions %>% {.} -> endPipe
```

If you have a better way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: You don't need `%>% {.}`. You can just do `pipeline_functions -> tmpWaypoint`.

Answer (score 3):

What you want also works using curly brackets such as

```
data %>% analysis_functions %>% {analyzedData <<-.}
```

And you can also extend the pipe after object assignment. I find it very handy to assign a dataframe at the end of a long chain before piping it into ggplot or saving a model object for other purposes before `tidy()`ing for example.

Cautionary edit: The dot notation to represent the current state of the object in the pipeline "." works only with the magrittr pipe `%>%` and not with the native R pipe `|>`.